# Run tasks immediately and then wait

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm new to Python and have code similar to the following:

```
import time
import asyncio

async def my_async_function(i):
    print("My function {}".format(i))

async def start():
    requests = []

    # Create multiple requests
    for i in range(5):
        print("Creating request #{}".format(i))
        requests.append(my_async_function(i))

    # Do some additional work here
    print("Begin sleep")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("End sleep")

    # Wait for all requests to finish
    return await asyncio.gather(*requests)

asyncio.run(start())
```

No matter how long the "additional work" takes, the requests seem to only run after "End sleep".  I'm guessing `asyncio.gather` is what actually begins to execute them.  How can I have the requests (aka `my_async_function()`) start immediately, do additional work, and then wait for all to complete at the end?

**Edit:**
Per Krumelur's comments and my own findings, the following results in what I'm looking for:

```
import time
import asyncio
import random

async def my_async_function(i):
    print("Begin function {}".format(i))
    await asyncio.sleep(int(random.random() * 10))
    print("End function {}".format(i))

async def start():
    requests = []

    # Create multiple requests
    for i in range(10):
        print("Creating request #{}".format(i))
        requests.append(asyncio.create_task(my_async_function(i)))

    # Do some additional work here
    print("Begin sleep")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("End sleep")

    # Wait for all requests to finish
    return await asyncio.gather(*requests)

asyncio.run(start())
```

This only works if `my_async_function` and the "additional work" both are awaitable so that the event loop can give each of them execution time.  You need `create_task` (if you know it's a coroutine) or `ensure_future` (if it could be a coroutine or future) to allow the requests to run immediately, otherwise they still end up running only when you `gather`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time.sleep()` is a synchronous operation

You’ll want to use the asynchronous sleep and await it,
E.g.

```
await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

Other async code will only run when the current task yields (I.e. typically when “await”ing something).

Using async code means you have to keep using async everywhere. Async operations are meant for I/O-bound applications. If “additional work” is mainly CPU-bound, you are better off using threads (but beware the global interpreter lock!)

Comment: Oh, so if I have any synchronous code it will block asynchronous code and prevent it from running?  I was thinking it could somehow spawn a thread in the background and continue my synchronous code.  In other words, is Python single-threaded with an event loop or similar?

Comment: So for this exercise I simulated synchronous work with `time.sleep()`.  What if I have non-awaitable processing going on (e.g. some mathematical calculations)?  Am I not able to run other code concurrently?

Comment: Yes. Event loops are single threaded, this is true in most languages. Sometimes you can await a thread join etc but in Python there is also the Global Interpreter lock, meaning only one thread at a time will run Python code (yielding for I/O), so it’s not that different from using async/await (only C modules are allowed to release the GIL)

Comment: If your math operations escape quickly to native code (e.g heavy NymPy operations) you could possibly use threads. If the loops reside in Python, you can’t and you should look at the multiprocessing module which spawns parallel Python runtimes and sync through shared primitives such as queues.

Comment: I'll keep playing around with it tomorrow but it makes sense.  I basically have a large loop with CPU-bound processing and HTTP requests.  I was hoping to continue doing the processing while the HTTP requests completed.  I'll see if I can find a good await point somewhere in the middle or maybe every x requests gather, then continue.  Otherwise my memory use goes up. :)  I'm used to .NET TPL with a thread pool which uses the async/await keywords and behaves differently than Python.  Sounds like this is more like JavaScript.

Comment: It appears the other key is to do `requests.append(asyncio.ensure_future(my_async_function(i)))`, otherwise the requests still only run at the end. Updating my question with a working example.

Comment: I think you should explore the alternative of using thread/process pools. You say you are CPU bound. HTTP requests need hardly any CPU so you probably are not so CPU bound that the network requests starve, but if you are, the only solution in python is a process pool. 'futures' are a nice interface to this, see https://github.com/ross/requests-futures

Comment: @TimRichardson: Yeah, I over-simplified for the question/example.  I'm basically reading stuff on one end (possibly awaitable), doing some processing (not awaitable), then sending over HTTP (awaitable).  I'm investigating the reading side to see if I can await there in which case that may be enough.  Otherwise it looks like your link would be a good option without getting into the multiprocessing module which sounds like it would be too generic/overkill.

Comment: @TimRichardson: I'm currently using `aiohttp`.  Am I correct in saying that `aiohttp` only works with the event loop/asyncio (lighter/less memory but could be starved by program) and `requests` creates threads (heavier but unlikely to be starved unless other OS threads are also being starved)?  In other words, is `asyncio` limited to the event loop and `requests` uses `concurrent.futures` which uses separate threads or processes?

Comment: You are correct about aiohttp. This is a good server approach ... but a good async server doesn't get caught doing cpu intensive tasks ... it hands them off to another process (or more likely, a pool of proceses). request_futures can work with either threads or processes. With threads it doesn't have a resource advantage over async, with a process pool you can access all the resources of your CPU. The threads/processes are heavier since there is more CPU admin in looking after them, but if you need more than one core, it's the only answer.